# The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' while creating method to save data in Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to create a method to save user data in the Firestore database
when registering with Facebook or google or with email and password

```
  void saveUser(UserCredential user) async {
    await FireStoreUser().addUserToFireStore(
      UserModel(
        userId: user.user!.uid,
        email: user.user!.email,
        name: name == null ? user.user!.displayName : name,
        pic: '',
      ),
    );
  }
```

and that's the code from a related class

```
class FireStoreUser {
  final CollectionReference _collectionReference =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');

  Future<void> addUserToFireStore(UserModel userModel) async {
    return await _collectionReference
        .doc(userModel.userId)
        .set(userModel.toJson());
  }
}
```

this error comes
[Code in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3ddw.png)
and this is the problem shown [problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFjk0.png)

It used to work fine before but after flutter updates, it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the new flutter update (2.0) sound null safety check were added and that might be the root cause of why you are seeing this error after an update.

I am guessing the name & email are declared as 'String' and you might have to change that into 'String?' or in the Constructor have that as a required field.